# TS: Common function with objects that have the same structure but different possible values on a property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, we have an app with multiple resources, let's say we have `Product`, `Cart`, `Whatever` resources. For each of those resources you can create activities, the main idea here is that for each resource there is an endpoint to create/update those activities, which looks the same no matter the resource you are trying to update.

So in our app (React) we created a single form to create/update an activity, it looks the same no matter for which resource you want to create an activity for, same fields, same possible values. Therefore we have one single component instead of 3, and a common function that handles the api part.

Something like:

```
const { mutate } = useUniversalEditActivity(variant); // variant can be 'product', 'cart', 'whatever'
```

We call `mutate` when we want to submit the form.

Inside that hook, there is a simple map:

```
const variantMapper = {
  product: {
    serviceAction: updateProductActivity, // simple function that wraps fetch, does the network request
  },
  cart: {
    serviceAction: updateCartActivity,
  },
  whatever: {
    serviceAction: updateWhateverActivity,
  },
};

// Using it like
const mutatingServiceAction = variantMapper[variant].serviceAction;
...
await mutatingServiceAction();
```

The `body` is typed as

```
type UniversalEditActivityBodyType =
  | UpdateProductActivityRequestBody
  | UpdateCartActivityRequestBody
  | UpdateWhateverActivityRequestBody
```

Which works when all the properties are the same across the types, but the problem starts now when the BE changed the spec for the `Whatever` resource.
So, before the request body had a property which had 2 possible values, so it was typed like:

```
type UpdateProductActivityRequestBody = {
  propertyWithIssues: 'a'| 'b';
}
```

All 3 looked the same, but the spec changed for the `Whatever` resource to:

```
type UpdateWhateverActivityRequestBody = {
  propertyWithIssues: 'a'| 'b' | 'c' | 'd';
}
```

Adding 2 more possible values for the same property, now there is a difference on how they look and inside my generic function that handled all body types, now I get the `Type '"a" | "b" | "c" | "d"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'`.

I kind of understand the error, but not sure how to fix it in order for my function to still work with all those 3 types when just the possible values on a single property is different between them.

I don't know if I explained as good as I should have, but it's a more complex question (I think), so I tried my best. Please also suggest a different title if you think it would better describe my problem. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**
@chris-hamilton, the request is executed like this:

```
const resp = await mutatingServiceAction(id, activityId, payload);
```

This is where the issue happens, because payload is a union of all those 3 types, but now they have become incompatible.

Minimum reproducible example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bessie-sxjc4x?file=/src/index.ts

I know in theory that the issue could be solved by doing something like:

```
if (variant === 'product') {
 // directly use product function
}

...
```

But I have the feeling this can be something different, as they have the exact same structure, just one property can have different values.

Comment: You've shown the error, but you haven't shown any code that would produce this error. You've shown types, but not where they are used. Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Dont like to use `as`? For example `const bodyNeedToSendRequest = bodyProps as  UpdateWhateverActivityRequestBody` or try use `T` generic type

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @AndreiOlar do you need to know that `propertyWithIssues` can have a value of `"a"` and `"b"`? Does that have any impact on the `UpdateWhateverActivity` function? Your example just has empty functions so it's impossible to tell. Please update your question with the example, not just an external link.

Answer (score 0):

This error is really just a big red flag for this design pattern. You've specified that these two parameters can be one of many types, meaning you can have any combination of `variant` and `body`. ie. this function would accept a `variant` of `"product"` and a `body` of `UpdateCartActivityRequestBody`. But clearly that is not how the function is meant to be used.

It's a question of what these `updateActivity` functions are doing, and how similar they are. It may be that the parameters of these functions can accept a common type:

```js
type Body = {
  propertyWithIssues: string;
}

function main(
  variant: "product" | "cart" | "whatever",
  body: Body
) {
  const serviceAction = variantMapper[variant].serviceAction;
  serviceAction(body); // no error
}
```

So you need to ask yourself, "do my functions need to know about all these specific properties?".

If the answer is no, then define a type with only the properties needed for those functions. If those properties are common for all functions then the design pattern is fine. The type may just be `Object`, it depends what the functions are doing.

If the answer is yes, then the design pattern is incorrect, and you shouldn't be coupling these service actions into a single function. You should just be calling `updateWhateverActivity` directly, with the correct parameter type. No need for this `variantMapper` object.

Maybe you have other reasons for implementing this pattern, but you'll need to give more details if that's the case.

---

I can see it maybe being the case that you have an object with `variant` and `body` and you don't know what they are until run time. In that case you will have to do type narrowing like you showed. But you should also be checking that the type of `body` actually matches `variant` or you're just asking for runtime errors. This is really what the error is trying to tell you.

```js
if (variant === 'product') {
 // somehow verify that body is of type UpdateProductActivityRequestBody
 // directly use product function
}
```